# Proving Pascal's Identity for more than two terms

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-combinatorics

This involves a slightly different version of Pascal's Identity but is still based on it.

Prove that
$$
{a \choose k} + {a+1 \choose k} + \dots {a+n \choose k} = {a+n+1 \choose k+1}
$$

I have tried to prove it using induction, but the algebra is quite cumbersome. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's not true. For example, when $n=0$ or $n=1.$

Comment: In general, this sum is: $$\binom{a+n+1}{k+1}-\binom{a}{k+1}$$ You can prove that by induction.

Comment: If you're looking for an elegant solution, I think combinatorial proofs are among the most elegant out there, and there are some in this site, look it up